# How to transform vector into array for Frequent Pattern Analysis

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am applying a frequent pattern analysis and need some help with the input type.

To start with, I use stringindexer to transform my categorial variables into numbers.

Afterwards, I create a unique number for each categorical value like this:

```
add_100=udf(lambda x:x+100,returnType=FloatType())
add_1000=udf(lambda x:x+1000,returnType=FloatType())
df = df.select('cat_var_1', add_1000('cat_var_2').alias('cat_var_2_final'), add_10000('cat_var_3').alias('cat_var_3_final'))
```

My next step is to create a vector with the features:

```
featuresCreator = ft.VectorAssembler(inputCols=[col for col in features], outputCol='features')
df=featuresCreator.transform(df)
```

Lastly, I try to fit my model:

```
from pyspark.ml.fpm import FPGrowth
fpGrowth = FPGrowth(itemsCol="features", minSupport=0.5, minConfidence=0.6)

model = fpGrowth.fit(df)
```

And get this error:

> u'requirement failed: The input column must be ArrayType, but got
>   org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7.

So, the question is, how can I transform my vector into array? Or, are there other ways for me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you don't need udf for creating unique number.Alternatively you can use withColumn directly like,

```
df = df.withColumn('cat_var_2_final',df['cat_var_2']+100).withColumn('cat_var_3_final',df['cat_var_3']+1000)
```

And also, if you are going this data only for FPGrowth model, we can also skip the vectorassembler and directly create Array feature using an udf as,

```
udf1 = udf(lambda c1,c2,c3 : (c1,c2,c3),ArrayType(IntegerType()))
df = df.withColumn('features',udf1(df['cat_var_1'],df['cat_var_2_final'],df['cat_var_3_final']))
```

Comment: You say that you don't need UDF and yet you create a UDF. I'm confused...

Comment: I meant, no need of udf for creating unique number for the categorical data from stringIndexer. The udf whatever he has in his code.

Comment: For some reason, Shaido's answer didnt work, but this one did. Thank you for the info.

Comment: @eliasah I was answering to Toutsos question not to Shaido.

Answer (score 3):

FPGrowth takes an Array instead of a Vector. Since `VectorAssembler` will give you a vector as output, a possible and simple solution would be to convert that output to an array using an `UDF`.

```
to_array = udf(lambda x: x.toArray(), ArrayType(DoubleType()))
df = df.withColumn('features', to_array('features'))
```

---

An better solution would be to do everything at once, i.e. not using a `VectorAssembler` at all. This has the benefit of not needing an `UDF` at all and is thus much faster. This makes use of the `array` function built into pyspark.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df2 = df.withColumn('features', F.array('cat_var_1', 'cat_var_2', 'cat_var_3'))
```

Comment: @Toutsos: Added a new, improved solution that works without using an UDF, it should be much faster.

Comment: The new solution does not seem to work for me. I get an error: TypeError: array() takes at most 2 arguments (8 given)

Comment: @Toutsos: Make sure you use the correct `array`, use `from pyspark.sql.functions import array` .

Comment: Did that, still does'nt work :(. For some reason it uses the python one..Maybe its python2 that is creating this mess.

Comment: @Toutsos: I made the import more explicit. To use the `array` function you need to write `F.array` instead which should force it to use the correct one. You can see if it works if you are still interested.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I will try it out of curiosity!